# Does correlation of inverse covariance matrix implies conditional independence?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, self-learning, quadratic-forms

I have **x** $= (x_1,\dots,x_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that **x** $\sim \mathcal{N_n}\left(\mu, \Sigma_x\right)$
$\Sigma_x=\Sigma_x^T$ and is positive definite matrix, can i proof that
$(\Sigma_x^{-1})_{ij}=0, i\neq j \implies x_i ⫫ x_j | \left\{x_k : k \neq i, k \neq j\right\}$
?
I get joint distributions with Brook's Lemma but i couldn't get any advance from there

Comment: Forget it, I already proved.